# select values that having maximum timestamp

Tags: sql

I have a table:

```
id|val|updated
1 | 31|2012-01-12
1 | 34|2012-01-15
2 | 41|2012-01-15
3 | 44|2012-01-15
4 | 66|2012-01-01
```

And i need to select id and val with maximum updated value.
So for this table result should be:

```
1| 34| 2012-01-15
2| 41| 2012-01-15
3| 44| 2012-01-15
4| 66| 2012-01-01
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This requires a `MAX()` aggregate in a subquery joined against the main table.

```
SELECT
  tbl.id,
  tbl.val,
  tbl.updated
FROM tbl JOIN (
  /* Subquery gets MAX(updated) per id  to JOIN against */
  SELECT 
    id,
    MAX(updated) as updated
  FROM tbl
  GROUP BY id
) t2 ON tbl.id = t2.id AND tbl.updated = t2.updated
```

Comment: `GROUP BY id` for what? Why it is required?

Comment: @aokaddaoc The `GROUP BY` is within the joined subquery, and is needed to correlate the greatest `updated` value per `id`. That aggregate value is then joined back to the outer table by way of the `id`. Without a `GROUP BY`, the subquery would return `MAX(updated)` for the whole table.

Answer (score 3):

A couple other 'portable' approaches. In my very quick test on SQL SERVER 2008, Michael's query performed best

```
SELECT T1.*
FROM yourTable AS T1
WHERE NOT EXISTS(
    SELECT *
    FROM yourTable AS T2
    WHERE T2.id = T1.id
      AND T2.updated > T1.updated
)

SELECT T1.*
FROM yourTable AS T1
LEFT JOIN yourTable AS T2 ON
(
         T2.id = T1.id 
    AND  T2.updated > T1.updated
)
WHERE T2.id IS NULL
```

Answer (score 1):

the selected answer will work just fine but here is a faster solution. It does not use joins are groups which will slow the query down. This one uses partitions which are much faster than groups and joins. Check it out:

```
select id, val, Maxdate as updated from
(
     select id, val,
            Max(updated) over(partition by id order by updated desc) as MaxDate, 
            Row_Number() over(partition by id order by updated desc) as RowNumber,
     from table1
)
where RowNumber = 1
```

Comment: if his RDBMS supports window functions... question is only tagged with `SQL` though...